# common elements in two lists where elements are the same

Tags: python, list, intersection

I have two lists like thw following:

```
a=['not','not','not','not']
b=['not','not']
```

and I have to find the `len` of the list containing the intesection of the two above list, so that the result is:

```
intersection=['not','not']
len(intersection)
2
```

Now the problem is that I have tried `filter(lambda x: x in a,b)` and `filter (lambda x: x in b,a)` but when one of two list in longer than the other I do not get an intersection but just a membership checking. In the example above, since all the members of a are in b I get a len of common elements of 4; what I instead want is the intersection, which is `len` 2.
Using `set().intersection(set())` would instead create a set, which is not what I want since all the elements are the same.
Can you suggest me any valuable and compact solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), then you could have a solution like

```
>>> import collections
>>> a=['not','not','not','not']
>>> b=['not','not']

>>> c1 = collections.Counter(a)
>>> c2 = collections.Counter(b)
```

and then index by 'not'

```
>>> c1['not'] + c2['not']
6
```

For the intersection, you need to

```
>>> (c1 & c2) ['not']
2
```

Comment: I think `Counter` can be useful here, but the OP wants 2, not 6, as the result.  I was thinking something more like `(Counter(a) & Counter(b))["not"]`.  (Or sum((Counter(a) & Counter(b)).values()) if we don't want to hardcode the word.)

Comment: @DSM `sum((Counter(a) & Counter(b)).values())` would break if they have more than one word, wouldn't it?

Comment: I thought we were given that there was only one word?  If there are multiple words, then you'll get what I think is the right generalization, i.e. `Counter("aabc") & Counter("ac") == Counter({'a': 1, 'c': 1})`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any particularly compact way to compute this. Let's just go for *a* solution first.

The `intersection` is some sublist of the shorter list (e.g. `b`). Now, for better performance when the shorter list is not extremely short, make the longer list a set (e.g. `set(a)`). The intersection can then be expressed as a list comprehension of those items in the shorter list which are also in the longer set:

```
def common_elements(a, b):
    shorter, longer = (a, b) if len(a)<len(b) else (b, a)
    longer = set(longer)
    intersection = [item for item in shorter if item in longer]
    return intersection

a = ['not','not','not','not']
b = ['not','not']
print(common_elements(a,b))
```

Comment: I meant `shorter, longer = sorted([a, b], key=len)` but that's not really as nice as I thought it was... but anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Do it by `set`. First make those lists to sets and then take their intersection. Now there might be repetitions in the intersection. So for each elements in intersection take the minimum repetitions in `a` and `b`.

```
>>> a=['not','not','not','not']
>>> b=['not','not']
>>> def myIntersection(A,B):
...     setIn = set(A).intersection(set(B))
...     rt = []
...     for i in setIn:
...         for j in range(min(A.count(i),B.count(i))):
...             rt.append(i)
...     return rt
...
>>> myIntersection(a,b)
['not', 'not']
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the following approach?

```
a = ['not','not','not','not']
b = ['not','not']

min(len(a), len(b))
# 2
```

Since all the elements are the same, the number of common elements is just the minimum of the lengths of both lists.